# get ssl certificate in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

i am looking to get the data from any given domain names SSL certificate. For example I want to put in any website address e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com" and my code would firstly check if an SSL certificate exists. If it does then I want it to pull out the expiry date of the certificate. [ i am reading Domainnames from DB ]
Example :http://www.digicert.com/help/

i need to create a web service to check expiry date. how can i implement it?? - I have looked up loads of different things such as RequestCertificateValidationCallback and ClientCertificates etc.

I could be completely wrong (hence why I need help) but would I create a HTTPWebRequest and then somehow request the client certificate and specific elements that way?

i tried the example provided @[SSL certificate pre-fetch .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509854/ssl-certificate-pre-fetch-net) , but i am getting forbitten 403 error.

Comment: please use details in this links as you want

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534908/transfer-files-over-ftps-ssl-tls-using-c-net?answertab=active#tab-top

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31624/An-FTP-secure-client-library-for-C

these links deals with ftp... but I got use them to as I want to get details about certificates. Try to use them to httprequest.

Comment: i tried using httprequest but i am getting 403 forbidden error

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check it and let me know its helpful to you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For this to work your project will need a reference to `System.Security`:

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

// Do webrequest to get info on secure site
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mail.google.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();

// retrieve the ssl cert and assign it to an X509Certificate object
X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

// convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

string cn = cert2.GetIssuerName();
string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
string cpub = cert2.GetPublicKeyString();

// display the cert dialog box
X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(cert2);
```

**.NET Core 2.1 - .NET 5**

You can use [HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-2.1) and [ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=netcore-2.1) Property. (This class is available in .net 4.7.1 and above also).

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
     UseDefaultCredentials = true,

     ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
     {

          // Access cert object.

          return true;
     }
 };

 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
 {
     using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://mail.google.com"))
     {
          using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
          {

          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: print values of cn, cedate, cpub

Comment: I'm trying it on aspnetcore 2.1. The GET request completes successfully but `request.ServicePoint.Certificate` is null!

Comment: @Poulad Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54063971/5755313

Comment: @Poulad Ah, great. Hadn't seen it. This was more or less also how I ended up solving it. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

[@cdev's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343898/5755313) didn't work for me on .NET Core 2.1.  It seems `HttpWebRequest` is [not completely supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/) on .NET Core.

Here is the function I'm using **on .NET Core** to get any server's X509 certificate:

```
// using System;
// using System.Net.Http;
// using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
// using System.Threading.Tasks;

static async Task<X509Certificate2> GetServerCertificateAsync(string url)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_, cert, __, ___) =>
        {
            certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert.GetRawCertData());
            return true;
        }
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url));

    return certificate ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

Comment: For .NET 3.1, this did not work for me to grab the cert at the end; I had to change `certificate = cert` into `certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert.GetRawCertData())`

Comment: @codeMonkey you are amazing. This was the solution I wanted and it didn't work initially and then you posted this! thanks, I would prefer this as the accepted solution

Comment: No, YOU'RE amazing @Hafiz! ❤

Comment: this was also the solution that worked for me in .net core 5

Comment: Some websites do not accept HttpMethod.Head. You could use HttpMethod.Get instead, but it will be slightly slower.

Comment: When you provide the URL make sure it is an https:// address (NOTICE the S).

Answer (score 6):

One thing to note is that you might need to set `request.AllowAutoRedirect = False`. Otherwise, if the server redirects HTTPS to HTTP, you won't be able to get the certificate from the `HttpWebRequest` object.

Answer (score 3):

Recreating the `HttpClient` each time you want to make a request is very ineffective and may cause performance issues. Better to create a single readonly client for all the methods. More informations can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests).

```
private readonly HttpClientHandler _handler;
private readonly HttpClient _client;
```

And this is my solution to getting certificate info:

**Code inside constructor:**

```
 _handler = new HttpClientHandler {
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        sender.Properties.Add("Valid", sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None);
        sender.Properties.Add("Errors", sslPolicyErrors);
        return true;
    }
 };
 _client = new HttpClient(_handler);
```

**Then you can read all the variables by:**

```
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.google.com/");
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
var isCertificateValid = (bool)request.Properties["Valid"];
```