# equivalent customHTTPProtocol in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, client-certificates

I want build app to make **`https`** request by using client certificate and show content in **`UIWebView`**.

I have an research, and i can do this with customHTTPProtocol in Object C. But i want build this app using xamarin.

I don't know how to do this in **`xamarin`**.

Comment: Probably need to search how to do in C#, not Xamarin specifically, then you'll have better luck. As long as the PCL subset you're targeting supports the .Net features, you should be able to use standard .Net features.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270764/get-ssl-certificate-in-net

Answer (score 1):

Your web service needs to be configured to use https.
And on your client it is enough to use the `System.Net.Http` library like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));                 
}
```

There is a bunch of documentation about this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Refer this it may help you sometimes :[`Org.Apache.Http.Protocol`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Org.Apache.Http.Protocol/)

You can also make a try with [`System.Net.Http`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient)