# Is there a "black box" method available to an ASP.NET web application to retrieve the SSL certificate of the server on which it is running?

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate

Is there a "black box" method available to an ASP.NET web app to retrieve the SSL certificate of the ASP.NET server on which it is running, a method that assumes no particular knowledge on the part of the application, something like "Get the certificate that is protecting me now?" Or does the ASP.NET web application have to know a relevant value to use as search term and supply it to the `X509Store.Certificates.Find()` method?

P.S. Is it possible for the web app to use something like what is described [in the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270764/get-ssl-certificate-in-net/15343898)? I don't see "ServicePoint" on the Request  in the web app's IHttpHandler.

Comment: There certainly can't be one that works in all cases.  For example, if the app is behind an "SSL terminating" load balancer then there may be nothing at all locally that looks like the cert the client sees.  For two TLS connections (client<->balancer, balancer<->app instance) you'd probably only see the "inside" cert, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I haven't had to deal with those complexities.